# My dock icon's animation is gone, what can I do to repair it?

Tags: plank

When I hover the mouse on the icons at the dock, they remain static.

Well, I remember there was an animation like Apple's OS;

Is there something that I can do to repair it? Or I'm making a mistake and there isn't anything.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

I just looked at mine and they are static, Don't remember if they have all ways been like that or not. Will keep looking for you.

Comment: I made a mistake, it indeed was static, but I done a search and found a tweak to make this animations, super easy.